# Autorotate is not working for google map created using google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autorotate

I have create a map now the map has to rotated in order to make it more nicer to see i tried the example from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/aerial-rotation where i removed time interval in order to avoid auto rotation but when i integrate in the application  i am getting following error 
ReferenceError: autoRotate is not defined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <style>
        html, body, #dvMap {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        #floating-panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 25%;
            z-index: 5;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
            line-height: 30px;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
        var markers = [ {
            "title": 'point4',
            "lat": '1.355333',
            "lng": '103.987305',
            "description": 'uuu'
        }, {
            "title": 'point3',
            "lat": '1.354432',
            "lng": '103.987262',
            "description": 'zzz'
        }, {
            "title": 'point3',
            "lat": '1.353199',
            "lng": '103.986908',
            "description": 'zzz'
        }
        ];
        var colorVariable = ["green", "blue", "yellow", "rose"];
        window.onload = function () {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                heading: 90,
                tilt: 45
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
            function rotate90() {
                var heading = map.getHeading() || 0;
                map.setHeading(heading + 90);
            }

            function autoRotate() {
                // Determine if we're showing aerial imagery.
                if (map.getTilt() !== 0) {
                    window.setInterval(rotate90);
                }
            }
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var lat_lng = new Array();
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i]
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.title
                });
                latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
                (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
            }
            map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
            map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

            //***********ROUTING****************//



            //Set the Path Stroke Color
            /* var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
             map: map,
             strokeColor: 'red'
             });*/

            //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
            for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
                if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
                    var src = lat_lng[i];
                    var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                    getDirections(src, des, colorVariable[i], map);
                }
            }
        }

        function getDirections(src, des, color, map) {
            //Intialize the Direction Service
            var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            service.route({
                origin: src,
                destination: des,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function (result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    //Intialize the Path Array
                    var path = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i++) {
                        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                    }
                    //Set the Path Stroke Color
                    var polyOptions = {
                        strokeColor: color,
                        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                        strokeWeight: 8,
                        path: path,
                        map: map
                    }
                    poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
                    poly.setMap(map);

                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="floating-panel"><input type="button" value="Auto Rotate" onclick="autoRotate();"></div>
<div id="dvMap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

please check what i made wrong in using autoRotate() function

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wexd3spp/20/, ajdust your functions to this example.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: autoRotate is not defined` because the `autoRotate` function is local to the `onload` function.  It needs to be in the global scope to use it for a HTML onclick function.

This removes the error, but aerial tiles are not available at that location.

**code snippet:**

```js
var markers = [{
  "title": 'point4',
  "lat": '1.355333',
  "lng": '103.987305',
  "description": 'uuu'
}, {
  "title": 'point3',
  "lat": '1.354432',
  "lng": '103.987262',
  "description": 'zzz'
}, {
  "title": 'point3',
  "lat": '1.353199',
  "lng": '103.986908',
  "description": 'zzz'
}];
var colorVariable = ["green", "blue", "yellow", "rose"];
var map;

function autoRotate() {
  // Determine if we're showing aerial imagery.
  if (map.getTilt() !== 0) {
    window.setInterval(rotate90);
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    heading: 90,
    tilt: 45
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

  function rotate90() {
    var heading = map.getHeading() || 0;
    map.setHeading(heading + 90);
  }


  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var lat_lng = new Array();
  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: data.title
    });
    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
    (function(marker, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    })(marker, data);
  }
  map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
  map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

  //***********ROUTING****************//



  //Set the Path Stroke Color
  /* var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
           map: map,
           strokeColor: 'red'
           });*/

  //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
  for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
      var src = lat_lng[i];
      var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
      getDirections(src, des, colorVariable[i], map);
    }
  }
}

function getDirections(src, des, color, map) {
  //Intialize the Direction Service
  var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  service.route({
    origin: src,
    destination: des,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      //Intialize the Path Array
      var path = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i++) {
        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
      }
      //Set the Path Stroke Color
      var polyOptions = {
        strokeColor: color,
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 8,
        path: path,
        map: map
      }
      poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
      poly.setMap(map);

    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#dvMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <input type="button" value="Auto Rotate" onclick="autoRotate();">
</div>
<div id="dvMap"></div>
```

Comment: thank you i am not very familiar with Google maps  please say me  (aerial tiles are not available at that location ) what does this mean and a any source  to know more on these things here,in the example what i need to do is i have rotate that lane which has the marker please say me how to go about it