# how to rotate a google map in a web application

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, rotation

i have a web application developed using google maps api i want to rotate the graph as shown in the second picture i tried the sample of 45 degree rotation from google api for this center: {lat:1.349992, lng: 103.985374}, value there is no titl for this location means what,
And when i integrate the sample application not is displayed in the browser original map before integrating rotation[image]

needed output is(it need to be displayed straight basically)
 [image]
 code where i have implemented the functionalities is shown below

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head lang="en">
        <style>
            html, body {

                height: 100%;

                width: 100%;

                margin: 0px;

                padding: 0px

            }

            #map {

                height: 100%;

            }

            #floating-panel {

                position: absolute;

                top: 10px;

                left: 25%;

                z-index: 5;

                background-color: #fff;

                padding: 5px;

                border: 1px solid #999;

                text-align: center;

                font-family:'Roboto', 'sans-serif';

                line-height: 30px;

                padding-left: 10px;

            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
        <script>
            var markers = [ {
                "title": 'point4',
                "lat": '1.355333',
                "lng": '103.987305',
                "description": 'uuu'
            }, {
                "title": 'point3',
                "lat": '1.354432',
                "lng": '103.987262',
                "description": 'zzz'
            }, {
                "title": 'point3',
                "lat": '1.353199',
                "lng": '103.986908',
                "description": 'zzz'
            }
            ];
            var colorVariable = ["green", "blue", "yellow", "rose"];
            window.onload = function () {
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                    zoom: 10,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    heading: 90,
                    tilt: 45

                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var lat_lng = new Array();
                var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    var data = markers[i]
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                    lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        map: map,
                        title: data.title
                    });
                    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
                    (function (marker, data) {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                            infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                    })(marker, data);
                }
                map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
                map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

                function rotate90() {
                    var heading = map.getHeading() || 0;
                    map.setHeading(heading + 90);
                }

                function autoRotate() {
                    window.setInterval(rotate90, 3000);

                }


                //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
                for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
                    if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
                        var src = lat_lng[i];
                        var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                        getDirections(src, des, colorVariable[i], map);
                    }
                }
            }

            function getDirections(src, des, color, map) {
                //Intialize the Direction Service
                var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                service.route({
                    origin: src,
                    destination: des,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                }, function (result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        //Intialize the Path Array
                        var path = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i++) {
                            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                        }
                        //Set the Path Stroke Color
                        var polyOptions = {
                            strokeColor: color,
                            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                            strokeWeight: 8,
                            path: path,
                            map: map
                        }
                        poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
                        poly.setMap(map);

                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
        <input type="button" value="Auto Rotate" onclick="autoRotate();"></div>
    <div id="dvMap"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

please point me where i am going wrong

Comment: related question: [Autorotate is not working for google map created using google maps api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707048/autorotate-is-not-working-for-google-map-created-using-google-maps-api)

Comment: thank you i am one who posted that question i have integrated that changes after that i am ended up with this i am trying to check what might be the problem

Comment: The problem (as I commented in my answer) is that aerial tiles are not available at that location.  That means the google maps javascript API v3 won't do any rotation for you.

Comment: can any one please say whether this is possible in any other api like map box to do it

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate the whole map div to make the roads horizontal, and rotate the markers to make them straight again fairly simply.  Making the infowindow work correctly will take some work.

rotation code from this question: [jquery animate a rotating div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776015/jquery-animate-a-rotating-div)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/v7L4ga54/4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var markers = [{
  "title": 'point4',
  "lat": '1.355333',
  "lng": '103.987305',
  "description": 'uuu'
}, {
  "title": 'point3',
  "lat": '1.354432',
  "lng": '103.987262',
  "description": 'zzz'
}, {
  "title": 'point3',
  "lat": '1.353199',
  "lng": '103.986908',
  "description": 'zzz'
}];
var gmarkers = [];
var colorVariable = ["green", "blue", "yellow", "rose"];
var map;
var degree = 0;

function autoRotate() {
  var $elie = $("#dvMap");
  degree = degree + 65;
  rotate(degree);

  function rotate(degree) {
    $elie.css({
      WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
    });
    $elie.css({
      '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
    });
    /* timer = setTimeout(function() {
        rotate(++degree);
    },5); */
    for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
      gmarkers[i].setIcon(pinSymbol("red", -degree));
    }
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    draggable: false,
    defaultUI: false,
    tilt: 45,
    styles: [{
      featureType: "poi",
      //elementType: "labels",
      stylers: [{
        visibility: "off"
      }]
    }]
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var lat_lng = [];
  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: pinSymbol('red', 0), // "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png",
      title: data.title
    });
    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
    (function(marker, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    })(marker, data);
    gmarkers.push(marker);
  }
  map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
  map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

  //***********ROUTING****************//



  //Set the Path Stroke Color
  /* var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
           map: map,
           strokeColor: 'red'
           });*/

  //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
  for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
      var src = lat_lng[i];
      var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
      getDirections(src, des, colorVariable[i], map);
    }
  }
  autoRotate();
}

function getDirections(src, des, color, map) {
  //Intialize the Direction Service
  var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  service.route({
    origin: src,
    destination: des,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      //Intialize the Path Array
      var path = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i++) {
        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
      }
      //Set the Path Stroke Color
      var polyOptions = {
        strokeColor: color,
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 8,
        path: path,
        map: map
      }
      poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
      poly.setMap(map);

    }
  });
}

function pinSymbol(color, rotation) {
  return {
    path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
    fillColor: color,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    rotation: rotation,
    scale: 1
  };
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#dvMap {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvMap"></div>
```

Comment: but if i do this scroll and drag options are working in unpredictably  way is there a way to retain those functionalities as it is

Comment: Nope.  The only option I found was to disable them.