# how to rotate the google map div with out changing the map dragging functionality

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, rotation, drag

The question posted below
[how to rotate a google map in a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747493/how-to-rotate-a-google-map-in-a-web-application)
can be use to rotate the map by rotating the div which contains the map

but if i do scroll or drag on the map the map is working in unpredictably way is there a way to retain those functionalities as it is

Note: i am rotating the map using div because the  aerial tiles are not available at that location.

Please say whether this can be done with some other map api are how to go about it in google map API

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer with certainty unless you post a more complete answer, but I believe your issue is with the corrodinate system.

You are rotating the display of the map, but the x,y coordinates of your mouse are not. When you drag the mouse, the javascript is capturing the mouse movement relative to the screen and then you are rotating the output by 45 degrees. In other words, google maps has no idea that you have rotated it. It would be the same output if you just turned your monitor 90degrees, the mouse is still going to send the same x,y coordinates.

In order to do what I think you want you would need to take over the code handling the movement or accomplish it another way. You will notice that the dragging is disabled on the example you referenced.

This might be a place to start looking for getting the center of the map on mouse events:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MouseEvent

You might be able to get the current coordinates and "transform" the new coordiantes by looking at this example of getting pixels:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates

Here is a page explaining some things about transforming coordinate systems:
http://www.continuummechanics.org/cm/coordxforms.html

If this is something that you really have to do, it can probably be done, but it is likely a lot more trouble to get right than it is worth for an average map embed. It might also add a lot of processing that will make the interaction pretty laggy.

After saying all that, I'd still love to see an example of this working so if you do make it work please post some code.